# Adding dynamic fields in JIRA

Tags: jira

we would like to create an issue in JIRA which tracks articles which a customer has purchased.
We would like to create a custom screen for this consisting of static customer data and a dynamic list containing the article and the article price.  When the user clicks on the "Add Article" button or link, a new entry would be made to the list of articles.

## Our screen would look like this:

Customer Name :          ACME WIDGETS_______

Customer Address:       Hong Kong____________

Article Name      Article Price

Widget________                                      100 HK_______

Sprocket_______                                          200 HK _______

Gadget________                                           300 HK ______

Add Article

Creating a screen containing the static fields, customer name etc is not a problem, however we have found nothing appropriate for dynamic fields.
Is there any way to create an issue with dynamic fields or should we be taking a completely different approach to realise our objective.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear of what dynamic data consists of, can you give extended example?

What you can do is

- Create different Issue Types for different types of articles and define appropriate fields for each type
- Solve this problem using issue links or sub-tasks: article would be master ticket, containing primary information and sub-tasks would have dynamic information.